# Total sale of current month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following sql:

```
SELECT CONCAT('', DAY(OrderUpdated), '') AS OrderDate, SUM(OrderTotal) AS ChartOrderTotal
FROM Orders WHERE OrderUpdated >= '2018-1-1' AND OrderUpdated <= '2018-2-1' 
GROUP BY CONCAT(LEFT(MONTHNAME(OrderUpdated), 3), ' ', DAY(OrderUpdated), ',', YEAR(OrderUpdated)), DAYOFWEEK(OrderUpdated) 
ORDER BY DAY(OrderUpdated) ASC
```

Above SQL displays are results as:

```
2, 20000
5, 2000
7, 8200
15, 1300
20, 1200
```

Now if i want all missing days also to results as zero.
as:

```
1, 0
2, 20000
3, 0
4, 0
....
20,1200
21, 0
22, 0
....
```

Also on WHERE i m using manually entered date.
How to get current month selected in WHERE CLAUSE.

FYI: OrderUpdated Date is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @mcv THAT PAGE DOESNT WORK. ERROR AS: The page requested could not be found. If the problem continues, contact the board administrator.

Comment: Looks like you might require a second table of ¨[Calendar Dates. Read over a similar situation here.](http://sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1225806-1292-1.aspx). FIxed it!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should group by also by ID so you could get all values:

```
SELECT CONCAT('', DAY(OrderUpdated), '') AS OrderDate, SUM(OrderTotal) AS ChartOrderTotal
FROM Orders WHERE OrderUpdated >= '2018-1-1' AND OrderUpdated <= '2018-2-1' 
GROUP BY CONCAT(LEFT(MONTHNAME(OrderUpdated), 3), ' ', DAY(OrderUpdated), ',', YEAR(OrderUpdated)), DAYOFWEEK(OrderUpdated), ID
ORDER BY DAY(OrderUpdated) ASC
```

Comment: how does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
SELECT
  DAY(OrderUpdated)                       AS OrderDate,
  if(SUM(OrderTotal), SUM(OrderTotal), 0) AS ChartOrderTotal
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderUpdated >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - 
  INTERVAL 2 MONTH
  AND OrderUpdated < LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - 
  INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY DAY(OrderUpdated)
ORDER BY DAY(OrderUpdated) ASC;
```

Comment: same result as before

Answer (score 0):

First, this seems like a simpler way to write the query:

```
SELECT DAY(o.OrderUpdated) AS OrderDate, SUM(o.OrderTotal) AS ChartOrderTotal
FROM Orders o
WHERE o.OrderUpdated >= '2018-01-01' AND o.OrderUpdated < '2018-02-01' 
GROUP BY DAY(o.OrderUpdated)
ORDER BY DAY(OrderUpdated) ASC;
```

To accomplish what you want, you need a `LEFT JOIN`.  A `Calendar` table or `Numbers` table would really help.  For instance:

```
SELECT DAY(c.date) AS OrderDate, COALESCE(SUM(o.OrderTotal), 0) AS ChartOrderTotal
FROM Calendar c LEFT JOIN
     Orders o
     ON date(o.OrderUpdated) = c.date
WHERE c.date >= '2018-01-01' AND c.date < '2018-02-01' 
GROUP BY DAY(c.date)
ORDER BY DAY(c.date) ASC;
```

Without such a table, you can create one in place:

```
SELECT DAY(o.OrderDate) AS OrderDate, COALESCE(SUM(o.OrderTotal), 0) AS ChartOrderTotal
FROM (SELECT 1 as dom UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL
      . . .
      SELECT 31
     ) n LEFT JOIN
     Orders o
     ON day(o.OrderUpdated) = n.dom
WHERE o.OrderDate >= '2018-01-01' AND o.OrderDate < '2018-02-01' 
GROUP BY DAY(o.OrderDate)
ORDER BY DAY(o.OrderDate) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : put your values in an array with days as index
Step 2 : find the number of days in current month
Step 3: make an array with all days and zero values
Step 4: add the two arrays using + plus sign

```
$date = new DateTime('last day of this month');
$month_length = $date->format('d');
$array1 = array(
2    => 20000,
5  => 2000,
7  => 8200,
15 => 1300,
20 => 1200,
);// you have to construct this array from your result
$array2 = array_fill(1, $month_length, 0);
$result = $array1+$array2;// addition with + order is important
ksort($result);//optional
print_r($result);
```

Outputs:

`Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 20000 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 2000 [6] => 0 [7] => 8200 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 [12] => 0 [13] => 0 [14] => 0 [15] => 1300 [16] => 0 [17] => 0 [18] => 0 [19] => 0 [20] => 1200 [21] => 0 [22] => 0 [23] => 0 [24] => 0 [25] => 0 [26] => 0 [27] => 0 [28] => 0 )`

Comment: this is so correct but difficult to implement on Google Bar Chart.

Comment: @Webgen What this has to do with Google ?